# Related topics in Power BI

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax

I have the following data model:

```
topics     topics_articles     articles
-------    ---------------     ---------
id         topic_id            id
           article_id
```

With `topic_id` and `article_id` having bi-directional relationships respectively with `topics[id]` and `articles[id]`.

I'm trying to create a new table to show related topics:

- Let's say I filter the report on topic `A`
- I get all the articles with that topic
- then I get all the topics related to those articles

So far I have this:

```
 topics_related =
 CALCULATETABLE(articles_topics, UNION(VALUES('articles'[id]), VALUES('articles_topics'[article_id])))
```

But no matter what I try, `topics_related` always contains all the topics.

**Could you give me some pointers as to how creating that calculated table please?**

Answer (score 0):

A calculated table cannot be responsive to slicers unless is computed it within a measure since they are computed only once each time the data is refreshed.

If your tables are related as you described, then you should be able to simply create a slicer on the topic and a table visual with the articles and the table should automatically do the filtering you've described in response to the slicer choices.